# Haussdorff convergence in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, hausdorff-distance

Let $\omega_n$ be  bounded open  subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$
such that $(\omega_n)$ converges to $\omega$ in sens of Hausdorff metric. I would like to know  what are the boundary  conditions, if there exist, that we must consider so that the closure of the sequence $(\omega_n)$, denoted $(\overline{\omega_n})$,  converges to $\overline{\omega}$ in the same sens. \

Thank you for your propositions and please could you provide me a good reference where I should find these kind of convergences.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $B(X)$ of all nonempty subsets of a metric space $X$. It is well known that $d_H(A,B)=0$ if and only if $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$. And thus the topology $\tau_H$ generated by the extended pseudometric $d_H$ has the following property:

> Two points in $\big(B(X), \tau_H\big)$ are topologically indistinguishable if and only if they have equal closure.

Topologically indistinguishable points can be defined in several equivalent ways:

- $x,y$ are topologically indistinguishable
- every open subset $U$ contains either both $x,y$ or none of them
- a net or filter converges to $x$ if and only if it converges to $y$

This should be enough to prove the following lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence (net) convergent to $a$. Assume that $(b_n)$ is a sequence (net) such that each $a_n$ is topologically indistinguishable from $b_n$. Then $(b_n)$ is convergent to $a$.

So all in all the answer is simple: none condition is needed: $\overline{\omega_n}$ always converges to $\overline{\omega}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if we consider $]-1/n,1/n[\times]-1,1[$ this sequence converge to the emty set , and the closure of $]-1/n,1/n[\times]-1,1[$ converge to ${0}\times[-1,1]$

Comment: @benabdellahabla $d_H$ is a pseudometric on **nonempty** subsets as ive noted at the begining. The notion of distance from an empty set is illbehaved. Anyway your sequence is not convergent in $B(X)$

Comment: I meant not convergent to the empty set (not a member of $B(X)$).

Comment: Isn't $(-\frac1n, \frac1n) × (-1, 1)$ convergent to e.g. $\{0\} × (-1, 1)$? I think that it doesn't converge to $∅$ not only because $∅ ∉ B(X)$. We can extend the pseudometric by letting $d_H(∅, A)$ be the same value bigger than any other present distance. But then it still doesn't converge to $∅$. The singleton $\{∅\}$ is clopen.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , I use the defintion of the Hausdorff convergence of the complement of the open sets, not the classical definition because Hausdorff convergence is usually applied to closed, often compact, sets, this is the reason to introduce the complements.                                               in terms of the usual Hausdorff convergence of closed sets. My question is equivalent to ask if given a sequence $F_n$ of closed sets converging to F, their interior converges to the interior of$ F$,

Comment: the uniform cone condition is enough to answers but i am louking for other answers if there exist